# Python Script to grep ppid 1 process in linux

Tags: python, linux, process, scripting

I have a query regarding how I can print Linux process with ppid 1 by using python script, as am new to python and tried to get some results from Google but I couldn't. In bash am able to manage by executing simple Linux command

"ps -u user -o pid,ppid,%cpu,etime,command --sort=start_time | awk 'NR == 1;$2==1'

Please help me with your answers. Thanks

Comment: If you are able to get the output from this command. You can simply run this command inside python script using os module.

import os
os.system("your command")

Comment: Try with psutil library in python. [link](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil)

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to add one point in my description, as by running "ps -u user -o pid,ppid,%cpu,etime,command --sort=start_time | awk 'NR == 1;$2==1' i can get the list of process, i also want to add if there is no output for this command say no process id found then script should return output saying no process found, can this be possible?

Comment: @sam: I tried running command inside python script received below errors
./testing.py
./testing.py: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `"ps -u user -o pid,ppid,%cpu,etime,command --sort=start_time | awk 'NR == 1;$2==1"'
./testing.py: line 2: `os.system("ps -u user -o pid,ppid,%cpu,etime,command --sort=start_time | awk 'NR == 1;$2==1")'

Script looks like this

import os 
os.system("ps -u user -o pid,ppid,%cpu,etime,command --sort=start_time | awk 'NR == 1;$2==1")

Comment: @Python: Looking at your code you pasted here, it looks like you have mistakenly interchanges quotes. It should be `"ps -u user -o pid,ppid,%cpu,etime,command --sort=start_time | awk 'NR == 1;$2==1' "`  instead of `"ps -u user -o pid,ppid,%cpu,etime,command --sort=start_time | awk 'NR == 1;$2==1" '`

Comment: Hi Guys, Still am unlucky to get the solution, as I'm trying to write one short python script which can grep all dead or old processes running in linux from more than 20 days, and  share the list in output. Idea is to grep basically PPID 1 process in this case, so it could be loop condition which checks if process found print the result else goodbye. Appreciate your answers if any. Thanks in advance